# Operator Overloading Return Type

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading, return-type

Here is a simple Code :

```
Iterator& operator=(const Iterator& other)
{
     node_ = other.node_;
     return(*this); // This clearly is a value
  }
```

In this we promise that the function will return a reference to an Iterator Data Type.

**But we are returning a value**...How Is This Working.....??

Seen this in many examples:

```
T& operator[] (unsigned int index)
{
    if (index >= numEle)
        return ptr[0]; // This clearly is a value
    else
        return ptr[index];
}
```

Its a very naive doubt, but cant really understand how this works.....

Comment: why do you say it is a value? It returns a reference!!! Why? Because compiler sees your function signature and is smart enough to return a reference, not value, based on return type of the function

Comment: A reference is **always** created from a value.  The conversion to a reference type is automatic.

Comment: *(this) is the value pointed by the this pointer...how is that a reference...?

Comment: No, `*this` is a reference to the thing pointer at by `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reference `T&` denotes an object of type `T`. We therefore always initialise a reference `T&` with an object of type `T`:

```
int x = 5;
int& r = x;
```

In your case, the return type is `Iterator&`, so you return an `Iterator` object.

You can of course initialise a reference `T&` with another `T&` as that other reference denotes an object of type `T`:

```
int& r2 = r;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should know that array elements and dereferenced pointer can be used as the left as well as right operand of assignment operator. It mens they can be treated as variable as well as value.

```
int arr[5] = {0};
int x = a[2];       // a[2] is on right side of `=`
a[2] = 5;           // a[2] is on left side of `=`

int *p;
p = &arr[0];
*p = 10;            // *p is on left side of `=`
a[1] = *p;          // *p is on right side of `=`
```

So, when return type of a function is simply a type, then `return` statement returns value. When return type of function is *reference* to a variable, then `return` statement returns *reference* to a variable.

Comment: I'm not so sure about `a[2]` ever being an rvalue in these examples!

Comment: @juanchopanza; I am little bit weak at thispoint because in C there is only l-value and r-value. But in C++, there is l, r, and pr-value and sometimes I get confused. My intention is clear that `a[2]` can be used either side of `=` :)

Answer (score 0):

It's **not** returning a value, it's doing as advertised: returning a *reference* (to a value).